# Azure App Service deployment Github Actions: Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern

Tags: asp.net, azure, github, deployment, yaml

I have a dotnet core app I am trying to deploy to Azure with GitHub actions CI/CD. However, the app is not on root repository but rather inside of another folder MYAPP. So I had to update working-directory of build and publish jobs but now I keep getting this error:

> Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
> Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern: ./published

My project structure is as such

```
├── .github/workflows                   
├── MYAPP  
├───── MYAPP.sln
├───── MYAPPTESTS   
├───── MYAPP
├─────────── MYAPP.csproj   
├── docs                    
├── OtherFolder                 
└── README.md
```

My YML file is as below

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - myappdeploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: './published'   

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true
          
      - name: dotnet build and publish
        working-directory: ./MYAPP
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build --configuration Release
          dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          
      - name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
            app-name: 'myappdeploy'
            publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_7894EB5E4C174F72A5EDE9C64B658907 }}
            package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Instead of working directory I have tried adding .deployment to root repository.

```
[config]
project = ./MYAPP
```

However this file was not read and the pipeline would say that it can't find .sln file. I have also tried adding Project app setting on Azure App Service configuration but still the pipeline would not work.

I have tried removing the package parameter of the azure/webapps-deploy@v2 and the pipeline runs successfully however I instead get the error when accessing the website:

[You do not have permission to view this directory or page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKYHS.png)

Also, none of the routes of my app can be found (404)

**When running the solution locally there are no issues.. and when deploying manually to an app service through Visual Studio GUI there are also no issues. However, this is not a proper solution as GitHub CI/CD is needed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might come into the same issue, I had to specify where the .sln is during dotnet build and where the .csproj is for dotnet publish. Also remove working-directory

```
      - name: dotnet build and publish
        # working-directory: ./MYAPP
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build MYAPP/MYAPP.sln --configuration Release
          dotnet publish MYAPP/MYAPP/MYAPP.csproj -c Release -o ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```